# Scheduled task restart service with dependent services

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, scheduled-tasks

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that acts as a Print Server.

Almost all of the problems that occur on this server is fixed by restarting the Print Spooler service.

I came up with a plan to restart the service automaticly every night, and i found this command:

> Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command { Restart-Service -Name spooler }

The problem is that my spooler has three services that depend on it, so this command will not work. Is it safe to add a *-force* command after "spooler" or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Just a quick note, you don't need to specify an execution policy when using `-Command` like that, since execution policies apply to scripts (files).

Comment: @HarryJohnston If i use `net stop spooler` I get the depentent services listed and need to enter `yes` to continue. I could do `net stop spooler /y` and `net start spooler`, but then the dependent services needs to be startet manually. I dont like to hardcode the start of these as well, since they could change over time.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting a service with dependencies nicely requires that dependent services are stopped first. There's a [Dell KB article](https://support.software.dell.com/appassure/kb/128574) with sample code. In case of link rot, a bit tuned version is like so,

```
# Service to be restarted
$restartedService = "FooBar"

# Get service dependencies
$dependents = (get-service $restartedService).dependentservices  

# information about dependent services
$dependentservices = gwmi Win32_Service | Select-object name,state,startmode | ? {$dependents.name -contains $_.name}

# Stop dependencies
Write-Host "Stopping Services" -f Yellow

foreach ($service in $dependentservices){

Write-Host "`r`nAnalyzing $($service.name)" -f Yellow

    if($service.startmode -eq "auto" -or $service.status -eq "Running"){
        Write-Host "Stopping $($service.name)"
        stop-service $service.name
    } else{
        "$($service.name) is $($service.state) with the startmode: $($service.startmode)"
    }
}

# Stop the service
stop-service $restartedService -force

Write-Host "Starting Services" -f Yellow

# start dependencies
foreach ($service in $dependentservices){

    Write-Host "`r`nAnalyzing $($service.name)" -f Yellow

    if($service.startmode -eq "auto"){
        "Starting $($service.name)"
        start-service $service.name
    } else{
        "$($service.name) is $($service.state) with the startmode: $($service.startmode)"
    }
}

# start service
start-service $restartedService
```

Comment: I think you mean "restarting a service with dependent services"?  (A dependency is a service your service needs, a dependent service is a service that needs your service.)

Comment: @vonPryz There seems to be a problem with the script.. The dependent services are not started.

Comment: @user3332631 are your dependent services set to start Automatically `$service.startmode -eq "auto"`?

Comment: @JanChrbolka Yes. The line `Write-Host "`r`nAnalyzing $($service.name)" -f Yellow` don't write out the the three dependent services, only one line with `Analyzing`. I have checked that the command `(get-service $restartedService).dependentservices` returns the services as expected. Seems to be something wrong with the foreach-loop.

Answer (score 0):

To restart a service with dependencies, in the latest versions of PowerShell (v5 onwards), you only need to include the `-Force` flag.

As in the example below with/out the flag:

```
PS C:\Temp> Restart-Service -Name "nlasvc"
Restart-Service : Cannot stop service 'Network Location Awareness (nlasvc)' because it has dependent services.
It can only be stopped if the Force flag is set.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restart-Service -Name "nlasvc"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceHasDependentServices,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand

PS C:\Temp> Restart-Service -Name "nlasvc" -Force
PS C:\Temp>
```

And as per the PowerShell references for [Stop-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service) and [Restart-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service).

Answer (score 0):

I think we can combine tips from other answers above, (powershell 5.1)

```html
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Restart-Service -Name spooler -Force -include (get-service spooler).dependentservices"
```

and you can check dependent services status, before and after

```html
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(get-service spooler).dependentservices"
```